# a basic table around the content

Tags: html, css

I am noob in HTML and CSS. I have content as shown in the image below and I need to wrap in a table again as shown in the picture using red colour. I tried with regular table format but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

```css
.bubble-info {
    margin-top: -12px;
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #0575e6;
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
      }
    }
  }


  .color-info {
    background-image: linear-gradient(91deg, #8cc6ff, #0575e6);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <br>
  <div class="col-md-4 bubble-info">
    <h5><b>Circle Size:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- No. of Students who got it wrong.</small><br/>
    Less &nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span></span> &nbsp;More
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h5><b>Circle Colour:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- Proficiency of the students.</small><br/>
    Highly Proficient<span class="color-info"></span>Not Aware
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `<table>`s should have `<tr>`(table rows) and `<td>`(table cells). You can't just shove random `<div>`s in there and expect it to magically know what rows/columns you want.

Comment: Why would you want to wrap that content in a table? Tables are for data.

Comment: sorry i tried with that one only but it didn't work i am removing <table> tag now i didn't see

Comment: @Turnip told by the manager

Comment: Are you wanting to visually style the element so that there are borders similar to the image? Or are you actually wanting to convert the HTML to a HTML table using the `<table>` element?

Comment: @Turnip boder color can be anything but content should be in table

Comment: Any basic tutorial should help you solve this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 2):

The Table is based around the  tag and inside the `<table>` tag there are table rows `<tr>` and inside those rows there are either a table head `<th>` or table data `<td>`. Here's an example driven from your code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th><h5><b>Circle Size:</b></h5>
<small class="help-block">- No. of Students who got it wrong.</small><br/>
Less &nbsp;<span></span></th>

<th><h5><b>Circle Colour:</b></h5>
<small class="help-block">- Proficiency of the students.</small></th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Less &nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span></span> &nbsp;More</td>
    <td>Highly Proficient<span class="color-info"></span>Not Aware</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Less and more have 2 bubbles but they aren't showing. it's working partially

Comment: use the css for your bubbles.

Comment: what should I do to display bubbles?

Comment: use css to build the circles ( bubbles ). E.g: in this url: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_circles

Answer (score 0):

If you used bootstrap, you should use col-6 for 2 column and create a border class for col-6

```
.borderred{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    <h5><b>Circle Size:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- No. of Students who got it wrong.</small><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    <h5><b>Circle Colour:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- Proficiency of the students.</small><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    Less &nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span></span> &nbsp;More
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
     Highly Proficient<span class="color-info"></span>Not Aware
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.borderred{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    <h5><b>Circle Size:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- No. of Students who got it wrong.</small><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    <h5><b>Circle Colour:</b></h5>
    <small class="help-block">- Proficiency of the students.</small><br/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
    Less &nbsp;<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span></span> &nbsp;More
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 borderred">
     Highly Proficient<span class="color-info"></span>Not Aware
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```